# Angular form validation: ng-show when at least one input is ng-invalid and ng-dirty

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

I have the following form in an Angular partial:

```
<form name="submit_entry_form" id="submit_entry_form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="SubmitEntryFormCtrl" novalidate >
    <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/><br />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email Address" required/><br />
    <input type="text" name="confirm_email" ng-model="confirm_email" placeholder="Confirm Email Address" required/><br />
    <span ng-show="submit_entry_form.$invalid">Error!</span>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The trouble I'm having is with the span at the bottom that says "Error!". I want this to show ONLY if one of the inputs is both "ng-dirty" and "ng-invalid". As it is above, the error will show until the form is completely valid. The long solution would be to do something like:

```
<span ng-show="submit_entry_form.first_name.$dirty && submit_entry_form.first_name.$invalid || submit_entry_form.last_name.$dirty && submit_entry_form.last_name.$invalid || submit_entry_form.email.$dirty && submit_entry_form.email.$invalid || submit_entry_form.confirm_email.$dirty && submit_entry_form.confirm_email.$invalid">Error!</span>
```

Which is UGLY. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Method 1: Use a function on $scope set up by your controller.

So with a better understanding of your problem, you wanted to show a message if *any field on your form was both $invalid and $dirty*...

Add a controller method:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.anyDirtyAndInvalid = function (form){
    for(var prop in form) {
      if(form.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         if(form[prop].$dirty && form[prop].$invalid) {
           return true;
         }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<span ng-show="anyDirtyAndInvalid(submit_entry_form);">Error!</span>
```

[Here is a plunker to demo it](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1xT4NUBhPZCgkyd0dBl)

Now all of that said, if someone has entered data in your form, and it's not complete, the form itself *is* invalid. So I'm not sure this is the best usability. But it should work.

---

## Method 2: Use a Filter! (recommended)

I now recommend a filter for this sort of thing...

The following filter does the same as the above, but it's better practice for Angular, IMO. [Also a plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/53W89Qlgpa9hALcUIuSj?p=preview)

```js
app.filter('anyInvalidDirtyFields', function () {
  return function(form) {
    for(var prop in form) {
      if(form.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if(form[prop].$invalid && form[prop].$dirty) {
          return true; 
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
});
```

```html
<span ng-show="submit_entry_form | anyInvalidDirtyFields">Error!</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. In the case that I type something in "first_name" the form is dirty. However, I haven't typed anything into "last_name" so the form is invalid. However, I only want this to show when there is an individual input that is both dirty and invalid.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was talking about. I'm just getting used to Angular right now, but I see what's going on. Thanks man.

Comment: I actually use a filter now to do similar things. I've updated the answer to reflect that. It's a little "better practice" probably, as far as Angular goes as it doesn't couple the logic to a specific scope.