# AngularJS - Form Custom Validation - Check if at least one input is filled

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

Good morning everyone,

Its possible create a directive (validation) to form level?

what I need is the following:

I have a form which has several fields and also has a button that is disabled while the validation of each of the fields is failed.

I need to create another validation, to check that at least one field of the form is filled.

I found one similar question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled), but the solution is not the best (i think)

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's an entire page on [angularjs forms and validations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) that can help. A search engine query for 'angularjs form validation' also has good results.

Comment: The solution to my problem is solved with a Angular filter.

See this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347024/angular-form-validation-ng-show-when-at-least-one-input-is-ng-invalid-and-ng-di

Answer (score 2):

My simple answer without knowing more details would be to add a simple function to your controller to check to see if it is valid.

For example:

```
$scope.isValid = function isValid(){
    return (field1 || field2 || field3 || undefined) !== undefined;
}
```

Then update your ng-disabled to include it.

```
ng-disabled="your_form.$invalid || !isValid()"
```

With more details I could get a better answer.

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that I had to put ALL FIELDS of the forms in the validation, better is looping.